# Problems with multiple alarms Android

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I've to create multiple alarms for my application. This is my lines of code:

```
public class NotificationAdministrationManager {

    private Context context;

    public NotificationAdministrationManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setAlarm(int cellId, Long timeStamp, String title, String message) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiverAdministration.class);
        intent.putExtra(SettingsData.TAG_TITLE_NOTIFICATION, title);
        intent.putExtra(SettingsData.TAG_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION, message);
        intent.putExtra(SettingsData.TAG_ID_NOTIFICATION, cellId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, cellId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeStamp, pendingIntent);
    }

    public void removeAlarm(int cellId) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,
                MyReceiverAdministration.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, cellId, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
}


    public class MyReceiverAdministration extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.hasExtra(SettingsData.TAG_TITLE_NOTIFICATION) &&
                intent.hasExtra(SettingsData.TAG_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION) &&
                intent.hasExtra(SettingsData.TAG_ID_NOTIFICATION)) {
            String title = intent.getStringExtra(SettingsData.TAG_TITLE_NOTIFICATION);
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(SettingsData.TAG_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION);
            int cellId = intent.getIntExtra(SettingsData.TAG_ID_NOTIFICATION, 0);
            NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setOngoing(false)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            context,
                            cellId,
                            i,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
                    );
            mBuilder.setLights(0x6098CF, 1000, 2000);
            //mBuilder.setSound(yourSoundUri);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            mNotifyMgr.notify(12345, mBuilder.build());
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(1000);
        }
    }
}

for (MyObject object : list) {
        manager.removeAlarm(object.getId());
        formatter.setCell(cell);
        manager.setAlarm(object.getId(), object.getBegin(), formatter.formatTitle(), formatter.formatMessage());
    }
```

Some useful information; the object.getId() is an unique value, but that can be used multiple times during the application, but during that loop only once. What I'm obtaining now, is that I'm getting the only last notification, after some seconds from the end of the settings of all alarms. What is it wrong with my codes?

Comment: int cellId = intent.getIntExtra(SettingsData.TAG_ID_NOTIFICATION, 0); Should 0 be passed every time?

Comment: Why are you calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` with `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE`?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with multiple alarms is very tricky. The problem on your code is that you don't pass a unique id on Notification Manager as result all the notifications are overrided.

```
mNotifyMgr.notify(unique_id_here, mBuilder.build());
```

Here is an example of my implementation on multiple notification alarms where I set a unique request code for each alarm and a unique id on Notification Manager.

```
 public static void setAlarmManager(ArrayList<MedicationPlanEvent> events,Context context){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    for(int i=0; i<events.size(); i++){
        MedicationPlanEvent medicationPlan = events.get(i);
        int request_code = 100 * medicationPlan.getId();

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if(medicationPlan.getTime().compareTo(TimeManager.getCurrentTime())<=0) calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);

        String time_model[] = medicationPlan.getTime().split(":");
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(time_model[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(time_model[1]));


        int stop_request_code = request_code * 10;
        Intent startNotificationAlarm = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        startNotificationAlarm.putExtra("Medicine", medicationPlan.getMedicine());
        startNotificationAlarm.putExtra("ID",medicationPlan.getId());
        startNotificationAlarm.putExtra("unique_id",request_code);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, request_code, startNotificationAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingNotificationIntent);

        Intent stopNotificationAlarm = new Intent(context, StopAlarmReceiver.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("Notification", request_code);
        bundle.putInt("MedicationPlanID",medicationPlan.getId());
        bundle.putInt("StopNotification", stop_request_code);
        stopNotificationAlarm.putExtras(bundle);
        PendingIntent pendingStopNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,stop_request_code, stopNotificationAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        int interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * medicationPlan.getTotal_days();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis() + interval);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingStopNotificationIntent);

    }

}
```

Notification Service

```
 @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String medicine = intent.getExtras().getString("Medicine");
    int id = intent.getExtras().getInt("ID");
    int unique_id = intent.getExtras().getInt("unique_id");
    //Every time the notification runs update the remaining days
    RealmDatabase db = new RealmDatabase(this);
    int days_left = db.updateMedicationPlanRemainingDays(id);


    String title=medicine;
    if(days_left!=-1){
        if(days_left == 0) title += " ("+getString(R.string.last_day)+")";
        else title += " (" +days_left+" "+getString(R.string.days_left)+")";
    }

    Log.d("Notification id ",unique_id+"");
    //on notification click  , launch recurrent transactions
    Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this, OverviewActivity.class);
    contentIntent.putExtra("flag",id);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, unique_id, contentIntent, 0);


    //done action button
    Intent doneIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationDoneReceiver.class);
    doneIntent.putExtra("id", id);
    doneIntent.putExtra("notification_id",unique_id);
    PendingIntent donePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, (unique_id * 16), doneIntent, 0);

    //notification builder
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_white);
    } else {
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    }

    //create the notification
    Notification n = builder
            //set title
            .setContentTitle(title)

            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)

            .setWhen(0)
                    //set content
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.time_for_medicine) + " " + medicine)
                    //set intent to launch on content click
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    //cancel notification on click
            .setAutoCancel(true)
                    //add the actions
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_done, getString(R.string.took_it), donePendingIntent)

            .build();

    //Sound and vibrate
     n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
     n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification manager
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //create the notification
    notificationManager.notify(unique_id, n);


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't understand why you you two id's for the peddingIntent and when you set the alarm, you also create the stopPeddingIntent.

Comment: The stop PendingIntent is used to cancel the first Alarm Manager that's why it needs different id.